# Problem with trunk between Cisco ASA 5505 and Catalyst 3750G

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, cisco-ios, cisco-catalyst, trunk

I'm trying to make a trunk between a Cisco ASA 5505 with the IP Service licence and a Cisco Catalyst 3750G.

Here are my current config's:

ASA:

```
interface Ethernet0/1
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 101-119
  switchport trunk native vlan 101
  switchport mode trunk
!
interface Vlan110
  no nameif
  no security-level
  ip address 172.16.110.1 255.255.255.0
!
```

Switch:

```
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
  switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
  switchport trunk native vlan 101
  switchport trunk allowed vlan 101-119
  switchport mode trunk
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/2
  switchport access vlan 110
!
```

I'm connected with my PC to the Gig1/0/2 with the IP `172.16.110.3` trying to ping `172.16.110.1`. The mac address of my PC is in the mac address table from the switch.

Can someone help me?

Please be indulgent with me, I'm a dev.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the ASA, each L3 interface needs to have a name and a security level. In addition ping (ICMP) is blocked by default, so you need to explicitly permit it:

```
interface Vlan110
  nameif inside
  security-level 100

icmp permit any inside
```

Comment: @Fralec: note that this is just an example, suitable for a lab/test environment, which I assumed you are using. If this is not the case you should configure setting the security level accordingly, and may want to restrict icmp access more granularly.

Comment: Yep, it's just for testing.